# laravel authenticate redirect error

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, authentication, laravel-5.4

problem is that :

if i open the browser ( chrome ) and write the url " localhost:8000 " page redirect as normally to localhost:8000/login. everthing is ok. if i change the url from the browser like localhost:8000/e/login ( this url is admin guarded segments ) page goes to admin login page.

i fill out the username and password area and click the login button and then

page should go to the localhost:8000/e admin dashboard but page goes to localhost:8000/login page.

why ? this problem occured when i open the browser first time and write localhost:8000 url and change this url to localhost:8000/e/login . other combinations is fine but not this.

why ?

> this is admin login controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\X\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers {
        logout as performLogout;
    }

    protected $redirectTo = '/e';
    private $continueURL = '';

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:x')->except('logout');

        if ( $request->has('continue') )
            $this->continueURL = '/'.$request->input('continue');
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('x.auth.login')->with('continueURL', $this->continueURL);
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->performLogout($request);
        return redirect()->route('x.login');
    }

    protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ( $request->has('continueURL') )
            return redirect($request->input('continueURL'));
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return \Auth::guard('x');
    }
}
```

> this is login controller for website

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

> this is RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        switch ($guard) {
            case 'x':
            if (Auth::guard('x')->check())
                return redirect()->route('x.dashboard');
            break;
            default:
            if (Auth::guard()->check())
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            break;
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

> this is authentication exception in Exceptions/Handler.php

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

    if ($request->ajax() || $request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Üye Girişi Yapmadınız'], 401);
    }

    if ( $guard == 'x' ){
        return redirect()->guest(route('x.login'));
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

> this is routes.php

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'e', 'as' => 'x.', 'namespace' => 'X'], function() {

    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    $this->group(['middleware' => ['auth:x']], function(){

        $this->get('/', 'EvalutionController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
        $this->get('/setting', 'SettingController@index')->name('setting');

        $this->group(['prefix' => 'evalution', 'as' => 'evalution.'], function(){
            $this->get('/', 'EvalutionController@allList')->name('list');
            $this->get('/{evalution_id}', 'EvalutionController@start')->name('start');
        });
    });
});

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    $this->get('/', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
});
```

> where is the problem?

Comment: Be aware that `$request->has('continueURL')` will return `true` event if the even if the input value is an empty string or null as of Laravel 5.5. This would result in redirecting to ''. Also in your constructor your are assigning a different param `$this->continueURL = '/'.$request->input('continue');` but never using it.

Comment: continueURL is a hidden input in login page. if i pass the query string to login page, continueURL setted with it.

in this example continueURL is not coming so continueURL input not created in login page and it means page should redirect to $redirectTo property value. right ?

Comment: Can you post the output when you change the authenticated method to: `        $this->redirectTo = $request->get('continueURL', $this->redirectTo);
        dd($this->redirectTo);`

Comment: output get only this : "/e".

sorry but i think problem is different from this.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question: so the problem is that you cannot access the /e route even being logged in as Admin?

Comment: yes. i logged in but not redirect to right url . ok ? i wait /e but redirect to /login . ok ?